# Filter multiple columns with same function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

```
=filter('Handle Database'!A:AF,'Handle Database'!Z:Z<>"Plastic",'Handle Database'!X:X<>"Plastic",'Handle Database'!Y:Y<>"Plastic")
```

Is there a more concise way of writing this? Instead of listing out each individual column separately?
Or should I use `=QUERY` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({'Handle Database'!A:AF},  
 "where "&TEXTJOIN(" and ", 1, "not Col"&COLUMN(X:Z)&" = 'Plastic'")))
```

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1skS4NSCtGFz5njK7LTuXEQMTom3EnrbeFutLXPUihPM/edit?usp=sharing
Not working for some reason look at the page "Filtered Database" please.

Additionally if I wanted to add more criteria such as Glass,Blue Steel,Wood,Oak. How would I go about that? And beyond that what if I wanted multiple other conditions that I want to filter the database by on other columns is that possible?